# How to make ul span margin correctly in before and same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Here is my CSS and HTML code:**

```css
.route-list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 9px 7px;
  background: #0097d6;
}
.plane-icon-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.plane-icon {
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-animation: plane 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: plane 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: plane 5s infinite;
  animation: plane 5s infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes plane {
  0% {
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  50% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  75% {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
}

@keyframes plane {

  0% {
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  50% {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  75% {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
}
.route-list span + span:before {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  content: "\f072";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  -moz-animation: plane 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: plane 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: plane 5s infinite;
  animation: plane 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" />
<ul class="list-inline route-list same-height-right" style="height: 33px;">
  Manila
  <span class="plane-icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-plane plane-icon"></i></span>
  <span>Kuala Lumpur</span>
  <span>Singapore</span>
  <span>Bali</span>
</ul>
```

I tried to solve margin between **before**, but it seems there's something that I can't fix it correctly.

I want to make it in **same line**, and auto width between cities and plane icon animated.

How to make in same line and auto width between cities? ((**SAME LINE**))
I'm also using bootstrap css, how to solve it even in mobile view small screen sizes?

**Here is what I want :**

> 1: single line 2: responsive 3: auto width between cities 4: fixed
>   width in  even in narrow size, texts will be resized based on
>   width. so how to make it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to set `single line view` for all these cities with same `space` between it.

Comment: Yes single line and responsive too and auto width between cities based on plane animated

Comment: I tried two different demos in jsFiddle, so please have a look [Demo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/y2ymfbk3/) [Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/y2ymfbk3/1/)

Comment: If you'll resize it then some of cities will be disappeared. It's not responsive. by the way, just copy it in html file and open it in your browser, then you'll see width between cities not set correctly. anyhow thanks for your attention.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what result you're after. If the cities don't fit on one line because the window is too narrow, what is supposed to happen?

Comment: let me make it clear, 1: single line 2: responsive 3: auto width between cities 4: fixed width in <ui> even in narrow size, texts will be resized based on width. so how to make it?

Comment: You want the _font size_ of the text to grow smaller if the words don't fit? That isn't clear from the question at all. Please edit the question and put that in.

Comment: Font text is not only thing that I want. I want something correctly. I don't want in small screen sizes, width won't be set. anyhow I edited my question.